# getting error in npm install in signature of ansi-regex installing nodemon

Tags: node.js, json, npm, nodemon

I tried `sudo npm -g install nodemon` but get this error:

`npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...q5EQXJ93KwEBWj7gSmuYa'`

The log of the error is:

```
184 silly resolveWithNewModule strip-ansi@5.2.0 checking installable status
185 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex 34ms (from cache)
186 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for ansi-regex@^4.1.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...q5EQXJ93KwEBWj7gSmuYa'
187 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
188 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1719ms
189 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
190 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
191 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
191 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
191 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
191 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
192 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...q5EQXJ93KwEBWj7gSmuYa'
192 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
192 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
192 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
192 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
193 verbose cwd /home/andre/Documents/2020/Web Development/EJS Challenge Starting Files/EJS Challenge Starting Files/ejs-challenge
194 verbose Linux 5.4.0-7626-generic
195 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "nodemon"
196 verbose node v12.16.3
197 verbose npm  v6.14.5
198 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...q5EQXJ93KwEBWj7gSmuYa'
199 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried `npm cache clean --force` and changing registries but it didn't work

Comment: yes, i have tried npm cache method and changing registries. @RobC

Answer (score 0):

`npm cache clean --force` is not enough to clean ansi-regex cache so `sudo npm cache clean --force` did the trick.